# Cannot edit Solr fields through Luke

Tags: solr, lucene, editing, indexing, luke

I am using Luke to browse some Solr indexes and when I try to "Reconstruct & Edit" a float field in my document and then "Delete old & Add" I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1106)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1021)
at org.getopt.luke.Luke.actionEditAdd(Unknown Source)
at org.getopt.luke.Luke.actionEditReplace(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at thinlet.Thinlet.invokeImpl(Unknown Source)
at thinlet.Thinlet.invoke(Unknown Source)
at thinlet.Thinlet.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at thinlet.Thinlet.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

with no other messages on why I get the NullPointerException.  I'm running the latest Luke 3.5 against some indexes created with Solr 3.4.  Any ideas what else might be wrong...?

Just to be safe I have stopped Tomcat and I have made sure that the index files can be edited from the user that runs Luke (trying to exclude the case where the problem might be user permissions problems on the index files)

Answer (score 1):

I would always use exactly the same versions for Solr/Lucene and Luke. This is especially important because you are trying to change the index in Luke. It could write out a version that Solr/Lucene could not read.

Comment: Did you mean that I should run Luke 3.4 against my Solr 3.4 indexes...?  I tried it and still get the same error!

Comment: Yes, Luke 3.4 with Solr 3.4. That is the only idea I have.